# Изменить пару символов с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: javascript

Суть такая, что нужно найти в строке символы `"-" "_"` и если они есть, удалить их.
То есть, есть строка к примеру `Exo-core` и нужно удалить `-`
Или в строке `Wam_Pam` удалить `_`

Comment: Что вы сами пробовали для решения своей задачи ? И почему именно регулярным выражением ?

Comment: Потому что мне нужно изменить строку, удалить именно эти элементы. Разбивать в массив мне не охота, хотелось бы более элегантный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = 'Exo-core';
str = str.replace('-', '');
str = str.replace('_', '');

Все сразу.
str = str.replace(/[-_]/g, ''); // Спасибо @MedvedevDev

Тот или другой.

if(str.indexOf('-') !== -1) {
   str = str.replace('-', '');
}

if(str.indexOf('_') !== -1) {
   str = str.replace('_', '');
}
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Да я так и сам мог. А вместе никак нельзя? чтобы или тот или другой. Или сразу два.

Comment: @Tom добавил в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, вариант str.replace('_||-', '') хороший. Но мне нужен именно глобальный поиск. Тогда не работает.
P.S. если одной строкой нельзя, то ладно.

Comment: `str.replace(/[-_]/g, '')`

Comment: Во, спасибо большое.. Снова выручил )
Когда я уже буду понимать регулярки..

Comment: а разве `.replace('_||-', '')` вообще работает???

Comment: @Grundy нет, не работает. уже проверил.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, тогда уж так: `/-|_/g`

Comment: @Grundy, а вот тут я сам засомневался ... такой вариант просто быстрее?

Comment: @MedvedevDev, как минимум на один символ короче :-)

Comment: @Grundy, хм, и ведь не поспоришь xDD

Answer (score 0):

А в чем проблема?

```js
alert("Exo-core_".replace(/[-_]/g, ''))
```

Comment: console.log лучше используй